# Who decides the layout and icons of a site? Are they open to vote?

Tags: discussion, design

So who decides, makes, or chooses the layout, icons etc for a site? And is there any voting involved? Is that voting open to general community?

Comment: Is this about Physics again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site design and icon design is not to put up to vote. It is done by the employees of Stack Exchange. The community can influence the design of the site by requesting specific changes on specific site meta. *Clearly not all requests are granted.*